# How can we display position and its element in R?

Tags: r

suppose there is a following vector
vec = c(1,2,-3.4, 0, 8.1, 1.9, 12,0,-1)

and I'd like to display only negative values with its index.

Should we use which() function here or can be done withuot it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by negative values with its index - can you give an example of the desired output?  `vec[vec < 0]` will display all values in vec below 0, for example. `which(vec <0)` will give the numeric indexes of those values.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name attribute of `vec` to record its values (i.e., named vector), then use `which` to also have the desired indexes:

```
vec <- c(1, 2, -3.4, 0, 8.1, 1.9, 12, 0, -1)
vec <- setNames(nm = vec)
which(vec < 0)
# -3.4   -1 
#    3    9
```